# Run macro in opened excel or start excel and run it in C#

Tags: c#, excel, com, excel-interop

I need to run a macro which is present in a excel file. This macro will create a new sheet in the file and fill data there. This macro can be called any number of times and it'll generate a new sheet in the same workbook every time.

There are two scenarios:

1. If the excel file is already opened, then the macro should be called from the same excel file instead of creating a new file.
2. If the file is not opened, then it should be opened, and the macro should be run there.

What I have done:

```
Application excel = new Application() { Visible = true };
excel.Workbooks.Open(pathToExcelXlsmFile);
excel.Run("MyMacro", parameter);
```

This opens a new excel, copies the content from pathToExcelXlsmFile and runs the macro.
How do I achieve what those two scenarios?

I'm running core6. I have tried do this to see if the workbook is active, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
excel = (Application)Marshal2.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
excel.Workbooks[pathToExcelXlsmFile];         // Doesn't work
excel.Workbooks.Items[pathToExcelXlsmFile];   // Doesn't work
excel.Workbooks.get_Item[pathToExcelXlsmFile];// Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

I use that:

```
string FilePath [ = Ofd.FileName ];
Excel.Application excel = new 
Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(FilePath, 0, true, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

if (null == wb)
{
  MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Excel Workbook '{0}' can't open...", FilePath));
}
```

then you have one reference Object to Workbook...

and Try lower permission:

```
excel.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityLow;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Creates new application and runs the macro there instead of identifying already opened workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to determine whether any Excel file is already open or not.

```
    public static Excel.Workbook GetOpenedExcelWorkbook(string fullName)
    {
        foreach (Excel.Workbook wb in EnumRunningOfficeDocuments("Microsoft Excel"))
            if (wb.FullName.ToLower() == fullName.ToLower())
                return wb;

        return null;
    }
    
    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    private static extern int CreateBindCtx(uint reserved, out IBindCtx ppbc);


    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    private static extern void GetRunningObjectTable(int reserved, out IRunningObjectTable prot);
    
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> EnumRunningOfficeDocuments(string officeApplicationName)
    {
        IRunningObjectTable Rot;
        GetRunningObjectTable(0, out Rot);

        IEnumMoniker monikerEnumerator = null;
        Rot.EnumRunning(out monikerEnumerator);

        IntPtr pNumFetched = new IntPtr();
        IMoniker[] monikers = new IMoniker[1];

        IBindCtx bindCtx;
        CreateBindCtx(0, out bindCtx);

        while (monikerEnumerator.Next(1, monikers, pNumFetched) == 0)
        {
            string applicationName = "";
            dynamic officeDocument = null;

            try
            {
                Guid IUnknown = new Guid("{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");
                monikers[0].BindToObject(bindCtx, null, ref IUnknown, out officeDocument);
                applicationName = officeDocument.Application.Name;
            }
            catch
            {
                applicationName = "";
            }

            if (applicationName == officeApplicationName) yield return officeDocument;
        }
    }
```

Your task can be implemented something like that

```
        Excel.Application excel = null;
        Excel.Workbook wb = GetOpenedExcelWorkbook(pathToExcelXlsmFile);

        if (wb == null)
        {
            excel = new Excel.Application();
            excel.Visible = true;
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(pathToExcelXlsmFile);
        }
        else
            excel = wb.Application;
        
        excel.Run("MyMacro", parameter);
```